# Why are set methods like .intersection() not supported on set-like objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, dictview

In Python 3.7, I'd like to calculate the intersection of two dictionaries' keys. To do this, I'd like to call the `.intersection()` method on their `keys()`, however it does not work.

.keys() produces a set-like object, however most set methods don't work on it. What works however is the extremely unknown bitwise operator overloads for set-like objects, like `&`.

```
m = {'a':1, 'b':2}
n = {'b':3, 'c':4}

m.keys().intersection(n.keys())  # Pythonic, but doesn't work

m.keys() & n.keys()  # works but not readable

set(m.keys()).intersection(set(n.keys()))  # works, readable, but too verbose
```

I find that the `&` overload on a set-like object is extremely rarely used and is not known by most programmers. Method names like `.intersection()` or `.union()` is self-documenting and definitely more Pythonic by this definition.

Why isn't it supported then? Even the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection) lists the `&` and `.intersection()` methods like aliases, not mentioning that only `&` is supported on set-like objects.

*note:* For some reason, in IPython the autocomplete lists `.isdisjoin()` as a method which is available on `dict.keys()`. Out of the 17 set methods, 1 is present.

Comment: If you're worried about being too verbose, you don't need to cast `n.keys` to `set` in the last example: `set(m.keys()).intersection(n.keys())`

Comment: While not disagreeing with the general point that the methods should be supported to match expectations, I find the overloads of the various operators rather intuitive, and prefer them to the overly verbose (and often confusing) names of the methods. I know what all the bitwise-operators do by analogy to what they do for bits; `^` makes sense immediately, but `symmetric_difference` always takes a moment to register; `<` and `<=` are immediately clear, but which one `issubset` mimics is not.

Comment: @sacul: For that matter, you don't need to call `.keys()`; `set(m).intersection(n)` will work equivalently, since `dict`s already act like unique iterables of their own values. The *only* reason to bother with `.keys()` is to get the set-like behaviors; if you're converting to `set` anyway, you don't need it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so you are saying that the cleanest code is actually: `set(m).intersection(n)`, right?

Comment: @hyperknot: Or just `m.keys() & n.keys()` (and actually, `m.keys() & n` works just fine too, but it feels weird to leave it asymmetric like that).

Answer (score 2):

[`dict` views only guarantee the API of `collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), not to be equivalent to `set` itself:

> For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class `collections.abc.Set` are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

So they're not claiming to match `set`, or even `frozenset`, just `collections.abc.Set` [`collections.abc.Set` doesn't require any of the named methods aside from `isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (which has no operator equivalent).

As for *why* `collections.abc.Set` doesn't require the named methods, it may be because they are somewhat more complex (most take varargs, and the varargs can be any iterable, not just other set-like things, so you can, for example, `intersection` with many iterables at once), and they may have wanted to limit the complexity required to implement new subclasses (especially virtual subclasses, that wouldn't inherit any of the methods `collections.abc.Set` might choose to provide).

All that said, I generally agree with your point that it seems needlessly inconsistent to omit the method forms. I'd recommend you open a bug on [the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/) requesting the change; just because it only guarantees `Set` compatibility doesn't mean it can't do more.

Answer (score 0):

The format should be

```
set.intersection(*others)
```

where other is any iterable.
m.keys() is dict_keys not a set so that won't work.

```
set(m.keys()).intersection(n.keys())
```

will work :)