# Why does dict unioned with dict.keys() return a set?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, dictview

As I originally expected, the union of a `dict` and a `set` gives `TypeError`:

```
>>> {1:2} | {3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'set'
```

However, surprisingly, the union of a `dict` and `dict.keys()` returns a `set`:

```
>>> {1:2} | {3:4}.keys()
{1, 3}
```

`set.union(dict)` also has this behavior:

```
>>> {3}.union({1:2})
{1, 3}
```

But `set | dict` does not, and behaves just like `dict | set`:

```
>>> {3} | {1:2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'set' and 'dict'
```

What's going on here? Why is taking the union of a dict and set allowed in some cases, but not in others, and why does it return a set of the keys in the cases where it is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary views are "set-like", but unlike `set`, they don't have the (type flexible) named methods (like `.union` as in your example), they just have operator overloads which remain type-flexible (since the named methods don't exist).

Being type flexible, they work with *any* iterable as the other operand, and `dict`s are iterables of their keys (`list({'a': 1, 'b': 2})` is `['a', 'b']`), so the values are ignored in the view operation. It's not that `dict`s are specially accepted here, they're just being treated like any other iterable (you could `|` a dictionary view with a `dict`, `list`, `tuple`, `range`, generator, or file-like object, and they'd all work, assuming hashable contents, and produce a `set` as the result).

It's not as bad for views to be more flexible because they're not intended to preserve their own type after the operation, they're expected to produce `set` outputs. `set`'s out-of-place operators are more strict because they don't want to implicitly give precedence to the type of the left or right hand side when determining the type of the output (they don't want `set OP nonset` to leave any doubt as to whether the result is of type `set` or `nonset`, and they don't want to make it possible for `nonset OP set` to behave differently). Since dictionary views aren't preserving types anyway, they decided to go with a more liberal design for their operator overloads; the result of `view OP nonview` and `nonview OP view` is consistent, and it's always a `set`.

The documented reason for supporting these specific operations is [to match the features of `collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

and [for some reason, `collections.abc.Set` doesn't require any of the named methods (aside from `isdisjoint`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53094334/364696), only the operator overloads.

Note: I'm not agreeing with this (I'd have preferred the views only have their operators work with other views and with `set`/`frozenset`, and that the views have the named methods as well for consistency), but it's too late to change, so it is how it is.

As for the `set` methods being type flexible, that was more of an intentional choice. Operators don't give a strong impression that one of the operands is more important, while methods necessarily do (the thing you called it on is obviously more important than the arguments). So the methods accept arbitrary iterables (and in fact, can accept more than one iterable, as in `{1, 2, 3}.union(range(5), range(10, 15))`) and return the type of the object they were called on, while the operators insist that the types agree to avoid surprises.

Comment: I'll note: There *is* a type inconsistency for `set`/`frozenset`, where `frozenset OP set` produces as `frozenset` and `set OP frozenset` produces a `set`. They wanted `frozenset` and `set` to be fully interoperable more than they cared about consistent types (by contrast, `tuple` and `list` don't combine this way, because they're considered a bit more different in meaning). C'est la vie.

Comment: Ah, having dict views be more flexible sounds reasonable. As for set, it was confusing since the Python docs seemed to suggest that the methods were equivalent to the operators.

Comment: @AndrewSun: You just need to scroll down below the individual operator/method descriptions: "Note, the non-operator versions of `union()`, `intersection()`, `difference()`, and `symmetric_difference()`, `issubset()`, and `issuperset()` methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')`."