# Subclass python set for deterministic iteration order

Tags: python

I'm looking for a *minimal* solution that exhibits the same API as set, but has *deterministic* iteration order. That is, the iteration order should depend *only* on the existing elements in the set. Here is a skeleton of the solution I came up with:

```py
class MySet(UserDict):
 
    def __contains__(self, element):
        return element in self.data
 
    def __iter__(self):
        # from a comment by @juanpa.arrivillaga
        return iter(sorted(self.data))

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{" + ", ".join([str(k) for k in self._keys()]) + "}"
 
    def add(self, element):
        # arbitraily map all elements to True
        self.data[element] = True
 
    def _keys(self):
        return sorted(self.data.keys())
```

Can it be improved ?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question you can post the answer and question together.

Comment: There's always room for suggestions / improvements. this decouples the question from solution.

Comment: Guy isn't talking about putting the answer in the question. Never do that. Guy is talking about the "Answer your own question" option on the "Ask Question" page, which lets you post an answer as you post the question.

Comment: The answer will be posted as a regular answer. It can be edited/deleted and other users can still post their answers. I'm guessing at least some of the downvotes are because it looks like a request for code without any effort on your part.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of the option - I'm actually not requesting any code - I was just missing this feature of deterministic set iteration so I though I'd share it - I guess it's still buggy - I'll fix it now.

Comment: There's [ordered-set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) on pypi.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, this is the reason I decided to post - because I though that a complete pip package is a bit over-the-top for sub-classing `UserDict`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom it's really not, implementing a sorted container takes some care to do so efficiently.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think the OP actually wants a *sorted* set. In which case, the excellent [sortedcontainers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library is a good way to go. Nowadays, if you wanted an insertion orderd set, I would just use a `dict` will all `None` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question what precisely your requirement is, but based on your implementation it's just a set where *only* iteration is in sorted order (it's still not semantically ordered, e.g. you shouldn't be able to access elements positionally and comparison wouldn't consider order, and *insertion* order doesn't matter). In that case I'd implement the existing `MutableSet` abstract base class and compose around a vanilla set:

```
from collections.abc import MutableSet
from typing import Any, Iterable, Iterator, Protocol, TypeVar


class Sortable(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool: ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Sortable)


class OrderedSet(MutableSet[T]):

    _values: set[T]

    def __init__(self, values: Iterable[T] = None, /) -> None:
        self._values = set() if values is None else set(values)

    def add(self, value: T) -> None:
        self._values.add(value)

    def discard(self, value: T) -> None:
        self._values.discard(value)

    def __contains__(self, item: Any) -> bool:
        return item in self._values

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return iter(sorted(self._values))

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._values)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({list(self)!r})"
```

The only custom behaviour is the use of `sorted` in the `__iter__` implementation. These are the tests I drove it out with:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from ordered_set import OrderedSet


class TestOrderedSet(TestCase):

    def test_contains(self):
        self.assertNotIn("foo", OrderedSet())
        self.assertIn("foo", OrderedSet(["foo", "bar", "baz"]))

    def test_iteration(self):
        os = OrderedSet(("foo", "bar"))
        os.add("baz")
        self.assertEqual(
            list(os),
            ["bar", "baz", "foo"]
        )

    def test_size(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(OrderedSet()), 0)
        self.assertEqual(len(OrderedSet(["foo", "bar", "baz"])), 3)

    def test_addition(self):
        os = OrderedSet()
        for value in ["foo", "bar", "baz"]:
            os.add(value)
        self.assertEqual(len(os), 3)
        self.assertIn("bar", os)

    def test_removal(self):
        os = OrderedSet(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
        os.remove("baz")
        self.assertEqual(len(os), 2)
        self.assertNotIn("baz", os)

    def test_rejects_keyword_args(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            OrderedSet(values=["foo", "bar", "baz"])

    def test_repr(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            repr(OrderedSet([3, 1, 2])),
            "OrderedSet([1, 2, 3])",
        )
```

I implement `MutableSet` rather than extending `UserDict` because:

1. it has better semantics, what we're trying to create *is a* mutable set;
2. it keeps you compliant with the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), meaning an `OrderedSet` can be used anywhere any other `Set`* or `MutableSet` can:

   - your implementation can be `add`ed to but lacks the *removal* methods: `clear`, `discard`, `pop`, `remove`;
   - your implementation also lacks the "magic" methods that allow e.g.:

     ```
     >>> OrderedSet((1, 3)) | {2, 4}
     OrderedSet([1, 2, 3, 4])
     ```
3. it gives us more freedom in implementation. For example, if sorting the set for every iteration is a crucial performance bottleneck, we can keep the same tests and interface and swap over to a [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)ed list:

   ```
   from bisect import bisect_left
   from collections.abc import MutableSet
   from typing import Any, Iterable, Iterator, Protocol, TypeVar


   class Sortable(Protocol):
       def __lt__(self, other) -> bool: ...


   T = TypeVar("T", bound=Sortable)


   class OrderedSet(MutableSet[T]):

       _values: list[T]

       def __init__(self, values: Iterable[T] = None, /) -> None:
           self._values = [] if values is None else sorted(values)

       def add(self, value: T) -> None:
           index = bisect_left(self._values, value)
           if index == len(self) or self._values[index] != value:
               self._values.insert(index, value)

       def discard(self, value: T) -> None:
           index = bisect_left(self._values, value)
           if index < len(self) and self._values[index] == value:
               self._values.pop(index)

       def __contains__(self, value: Any) -> bool:
           index = bisect_left(self._values, value)
           return index < len(self) and self._values[index] == value

       def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
           return iter(self._values)

       def __len__(self) -> int:
           return len(self._values)

       def __repr__(self) -> str:
           return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self._values!r})"
   ```

* *but not where any `set` can, see e.g. [Why are set methods like .intersection() not supported on set-like objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53094334/3001761)*

Comment: Yes, the only customized behavior is sorted iteration. Is there any complexity penalty for the `UserDict` ? or other reason(s) you chose to subclass `MutableSet` ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom for one thing implementing `MutableSet` has better semantics - that's the kind of thing I'm actually trying to create, an `OrderedSet` _is a_ mutable set. It also gives you more choice on the implementation - e.g. if performance is critical and sorting every iteration is costly then it might be better to compose around a list, instead of a set, and [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) it.

Comment: thanks ! one last question - what is `/)` in your `__init__` ? I thought it was a typo but the code works ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/ (it's what makes `test_rejects_keyword_args` pass to match the real `set` creation interface).